# Transform array to another format

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5, nested

The following code is a return of my function for display categories list.

My structure:

Parent_category -> Category -> Child_category

Now i combine child_category with category and add to `category` `is_bold` param.

Here's method:

```
public function categories(){
  $categories = self::buildTree(Category::get()->toArray());
  $cats = $categories;
  foreach($cats as $key=>$category){
    if(count($category['childs'])>0){
      foreach($category['childs'] as $key1=>$c){
        if(count($c['childs'])>0){
          $categories[$key]['childs'] = array_merge($categories[$key]['childs'], $c['childs']);
          unset($categories[$key]['childs'][$key1]['childs']);
          $categories[$key]['childs'][$key1]['is_bold']=1;
        }
      }
      $categories[$key]['childs'] = self::array_sort($categories[$key]['childs'], 'id', SORT_ASC);
    }
  }
  return response()->json(array('data' => $categories), 200);
}
```

Here's buildTree method:

```
public static function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = null){
  $result = array();
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
      if($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
          $children = self::buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
          $element['childs'] = [];
          if ($children) $element['childs'] = $children;
          $result[$element['id']] = $element;
      }
  }
  return array_values($result);
}
```

Here's my return

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": null,
  "name": "tv",
  "icon": null,
  "slack": null,
  "childs": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "name": "tvs",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "is_bold": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "parent_id": 2,
      "name": "LED tvs",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "childs": []
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "parent_id": 2,
      "name": "4K tvs",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "childs": []
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "name": "videos",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "is_bold": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "home cinema",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "childs": []
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "videoplayers",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "childs": []
    }]
 }]
```

But now I want to return data like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": null,
  "name": "Телевизоры, аудио, видео",
  "icon": null,
  "slack": null,
  "childs": [
   "televizory": [ {
      "id": 2,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "name": "Телевизоры",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "is_bold": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "parent_id": 2,
      "name": "LED телевизоры",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
   },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "parent_id": 2,
      "name": "4K Телевизоры",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
   }],
  video": [  {
      "id": 5,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "name": "Домашнее видео, аудио",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
      "is_bold": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "Домашние кинотеатры",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "Видеоплееры",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
   },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "Проекторы",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "Акустика Hi-Fi",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "parent_id": 5,
      "name": "Аксессуары",
      "icon": null,
      "slack": null,
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Laravel's **Collection** class.

Simply replace

```
if ($children) $element['childs'] = $children;
```

with

```
if ($children)  {
  $children = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($children);
  $element['childs'] = $children->keyBy('name')->toArray();
}
```

The **keyBy()** method replaces the keys of collection's elements with the value of selected attribute of those elements - **name** in your case.